# How to select a <td> with a specific value?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have created a Calendar in react and the code looks like this

```
import React, {Component, useRef} from 'react';
import './calendar.css';

function round(v) {
  return Math.ceil(v * Math.pow(10, 0)) / Math.pow(10, 0);
}

let year = new Date().getFullYear();
let months = [
  'January',
  'February',
  'March',
  'April',
  'May',
  'June',
  'July',
  'August',
  'September',
  'October',
  'November',
  'December',
];

function GenerateRows(month, calendar) {
    const inputEl = useRef("");
  const onButtonClick = () => {
    // `current` points to the mounted text input element
    inputEl.current.focus()
  };
  let rowsNeeded = round(calendar[month].length / 7);
  let rows = [];

  let delayBy = new Date(year, months.indexOf(month), 1).getDay();

    const myRef = React.createRef

    let day = 0
    let iteration = 0


  for (let i = 0; i < rowsNeeded; i++) {
    let row = [];

    for (let j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            iteration++
            if(iteration < delayBy){
                row.push(<td className="spacer"></td>)
                continue
            }else{
                if(day === calendar[month].length){
                    row.push(<td className="spacer"></td>)
                }else{
                    day++
                    row.push(<td ref={myRef} onClick={onButtonClick}>{day}</td>)
                }
            }
        }

    rows.push(<tr>{row}</tr>);
  }

  return (
    <table>
      <tbody>{rows}</tbody>
    </table>
  );
}

export default function Week() {
  let calendar = {};

  months.forEach((month, index) => {
    let daysInMonth = new Date(year, index + 1, 0).getDate();

    calendar[month] = Array.from({ length: daysInMonth }, (_, i) => i + 1);

    console.log(month);
  });


  return (
        <div className="calendar">
            <div className="calendar-year">
                {months.map((month) => (
                    <div className='calendar-month'>
                        <span className='month-name'>{month.slice(0, 3)}</span>
                        {GenerateRows(month, calendar)}
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
  );
}
```

This displays a Calendar for the whole year. Now I want to be able to give some  elements with a specific value a className. So for example the 1 in January is supposed to have the className="red". How would I do this? I have tried using refs but haven't really gotten my head around it yet.

[image: The calendar looks like this]

Comment: Add the logic when you are generating the calendar. Do you want to manipulate it only after generation?

Comment: yes, I get data from an api, and this gives me the dates which should be selected

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve your goal, is using CSS *pseudo-classes*, such as [:first-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child).

For example:

```css
.calendar-month table tbody tr td:first-child {
  color: red;
}
```

You can get creative with other pseudo-classes such as [:nth-child()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child), [:nth-last-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-last-child), and [more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes).

However this can be limited based on your requirements, in such case you would be better off implementing custom logic in your code. Also it can be a bit harder to make it work if you have other sibling elements such as empty `<td>` for spacing, and more.

So an alternative you could use would be implementing it in your code.

See the example below, to add the className "red" on the `<td>` element that has the first day of each month.

```js
    for (let j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            iteration++
            if(iteration < delayBy){
                row.push(<td className="spacer"></td>)
                continue
            }else{
                if(day === calendar[month].length){
                    row.push(<td className="spacer"></td>)
                }else{
                    day++
                    // a logic check for your requirement
                    const isFirstDay = day === 1;
                    // append a custom className when needed
                    row.push(<td className={isFirstDay ? "red" : ""} ref={myRef} onClick={onButtonClick}>{day}</td>)
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Silly codepen link : https://codepen.io/ktdev/pen/qBqVyyx (You might need to see how to select a particular id based on the month and day, don't have enough time to calculate that, but this is the idea on how you can change the color using refs)

```
inputRefs = [];

setRef = (ref) => {
  this.inputRefs.push(ref);
};
```

Add this while generating the tags.

```
<td ref={this.setRef} onClick={onButtonClick}>
  {day}
</td>
```

and use this to select td

```
onClick={() => changeInput(1)}

changeInput = (id, month) => {
  return (inputRefs[id].style.background = "red");
};
```